# Cannot install packages in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

I am installing Julia packages in Linux system. The error message is below. There are three kinds of error message. I don't know how to fix it. I have already tried pkg> update. It didn't help. The julia version is Version 1.0.0 (2018-08-08).
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do the same errors pop out, when you install it directly from the central registry (`]add NLopt` instead of the git-address)?

Comment: I tried that. The error message is that ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * NLopt (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.

Comment: Easiest solution would be to just delete your `~/.julia` directory. That way, when you next start Julia, it will build fresh copies of all package management files. The downside is that you'll have to re-install all the packages you've already installed. Make sure you haven't put anything important of your own in that directory before deleting. You could always just re-name it to `~/.julia_OLD` if you wanted to be safe.

Comment: Deleting `~/.julia` should never be needed anymore, since Julia 1.0. The problem here is probably that you do not have a registry. You can remove the content of `~/.julia/registries` and retry.

Comment: I fixed the problem. First, run rm(joinpath(homedir(), ".julia", "registries"); recursive=true). Then run cd("$(homedir())/.julia"). The package will be installed.